# Using 3 different Esri BaseMaps on different pages in Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I'm trying to use 3 different basemaps, Imagery, transportation, and hydrology in my data driven pages.  They are saved and added to the map document as Layer files (.lyr) I would like to use both transportation and hydrology on one page, Imagery and hydrology on another, imagery on one page, and hydrology on another page. The data for the pages varies, too. But it is controlled using the "Page Definition' function.  The .lyr files do not have this function available in their properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could set scale visibility slightly different on the Three basemaps, for example 10000,10001 and 10002. Then add a field to your index layer and populate with scale depending on which basemap you want to use. Then use the scale field to set scale for the ddp. Will of course only work with if you are ok with a limited number of scales. But i doubt it is possible to use two different basemaps in the same Data Frame. But you could add more Data Frames..

Comment: You might get some flexibility by using layers consisting of  white polygons that blocks everything under it, sandwiched between your base layers,  then attributing its fields such that you could use page definitions to turn each off or on to block the base layers under it. But that does require some setup time.